# Which layout to use to ensure fixed proportion of component size?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I want a swing layout where components can be placed ANYWHERE (and not fixed locations) one likes and the location of components does not change and their sizes (relative to each) other remains in  a fixed proportion. When the outermost frame is resized, everything looks the same, except only that its much bigger or smaller due to the resizing.

I saw that Border forces me to put everything into one of its few fixed locations. I don't really like that. Grid and Flow are not what I need. Which is the best layout for this ? Could it be MigLayout ?

![Can I do this VERY EASILY using a swing layout ? It should almost be a no-brainer to use and there should be no complexities involved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og7F3.jpg)

Comment: No, there is no way to do this that doesn't involve some complexities.  There is practically nothing you can do in UI layout in ANY system that doesn't involve some complexities.

Comment: @rcook - I did not say 0 complexities. But the lesser, the better. So, what could my options possibly be ?

Comment: *"Can I do this VERY EASILY..."* No.  You've just asked for an incredibly complex solution, which needs to take into consideration *n* number of possibilities.

Comment: You could take a look at [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) and even [JGoodies FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/)

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken then -- you said "no complexities", and I equated that with "0 complexities".  My apologies.  I have no idea what you expect, and therefore have no confidence that I can help you.

Comment: I feel like the NetBeans GUI builder used to create this kind of layout somehow.  I think it involved the GUI builder passing the x,y location of every single component into an underlying layout of some kind.

Comment: @rcook - sorry. i was not clear. I fixed the image now.

Comment: @Pace - I don't want any gui builder tool. I want to do it on my own, by hand.

Comment: @SuperStar Right, but you can use the GuiBuilder to generate the layout and look at how they do it then do that yourself.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Would MigLayout also be worth considering here ?

Comment: @SuperStar I've not used it, but I'd be willing to add it to the list

Comment: `Which is the best layout for this`. You don't always have to use a single layout manager. For example maybe you start with a BorderLayout. The panel on the right goes the the EAST and the rest go to the CENTER. Then you break the center panel down to use a panel with a different layout.

Comment: @Pace While Netbeans form editor can use a `null` layout, it uses `GroupLayout` by default (if I remember correctly)

Comment: @camickr - oh yes! I think you should put that as an answer. May be I won't really need spring, mig etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which is the best layout for this.

You don't always have to use a single layout manager.

For example maybe you start with a BorderLayout. The panel on the right goes the the EAST and the rest go to the CENTER. Then you break the center panel down to use a panel with a different layout.